While running python selenium script the chrome browser executes it very quickly
I am currently learning Selenium in Python,
I was executing the following script
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import *;

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

def timing(driver):
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR , "input#email").send_keys("abc")

When I ran this script it was so quick I could not see the UI flow while executing.
Is there any way to slow this down? I tried adding waits but the view didn't improve much.

I think you don't need to use ChromeDriverManager
just use webdriver.Chrome()
here is the complete code example | and dont forget to call timing function
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import *

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
def timing(driver):
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR , "input#email").send_keys("abc")

timing(driver)

if you want to add the headless option, you can add this line of code
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

And finally, at the end of the code, you need to close the driver to prevent it from accumulating in the background
driver.close()

complete code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import *

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
# options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless=new')
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # You can enter options if necessary
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
def timing(driver):
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR , "input#email").send_keys("abc")
    
timing(driver)
driver.close()


You can add delays like time.sleep(5) which delay the flow of execution for 5 seconds.

Yup that Works For Me

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-testid=royal_email]").send_keys("abc@gmail.com")
time.sleep(10)

ImplicitWait(N) is used to tell the WebDriver to wait (N) before throwing an exception, whereas your code is error-free , therefore it doesn't wait at all.
Just use time.sleep(3). It pauses the execution of the code for 3 seconds then it will continue the execution after that.
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import *;

driver = 
webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

def timing(driver):
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR , "input#email").send_keys("abc")

timing(driver)
time.sleep(3)
driver.close()

